# Replace character with page break

Tags: ms-word

In MS Word I need to string replace a pattern (`$$$newpage`) with a page break. Is this possible with standard page search? Or do I need to do it programmatically?

Comment: Just to address Illidanek's response to alfasin, I believe that in Open Office you have to go into options and select 'Show hidden characters' before doing the search and replace if you don't want it to display the formatting shortcut as raw text. This step is not necessary with my MS Word 2016, but perhaps with some other versions of Word?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

go to "find and replace" and enter your "find" character and replace it with `^m` 
You can read more about it *[here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/find-and-replace-text-or-other-items-HA001230392.aspx#_Toc282602052)*

Comment: I already have ^m in my document, however it displays as "^m" instead of creating a page break. Are any steps required after the 'find and replace'?

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem but my need is to replace Section Break "^b" with page break "^m". Find and replaxce doesn't work for me. 
I resolved using this VBA script:

```
Sub ReplaceSectionBreaks()
    'reliably replace section breaks with page breaks
    'even if they're followed by tables
    Dim rg As Range
    Set rg = ActiveDocument.Range
    With rg.Find
        .Text = "^b"
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
        While .Execute
            rg.Delete
            rg.InsertBreak Type:=wdPageBreak
            rg.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
        Wend
    End With
End Sub
```

try to change "^b" with your pattern "$$$newpage", it should to work for you too.